# Date column(Event_date) fall between Date Start_date and End_date in DF(python)

Tags: python, dataframe

```
  V     EVENT DATE  Start Date  END DATE
 AA1    8-Aug-19    5-Aug-19    15-Aug-19
 AA2    8-Aug-19    8-Aug-19    15-Aug-19
 AA3    8-Aug-19    8-Aug-19    8-Aug-19
 AA4    8-Aug-19    6-Aug-19    15-Aug-19
 AA5    8-Aug-19    15-Aug-19   20-Aug-19
 AA6    8-Aug-19    12-Aug-19   20-Aug-19
```

1. I want to capture the Event date fall between the start and End Date
2. Second one i want to add the start and end date + 5 day and event date falling within new start+5days and end+5days date
3. Third one I want to add the start and end date - 5 day and  event date  falling within new star-5days and end-5days date

Comment: what is your question exactly? how someone can understand your problem just by seeing an iamge

Comment: I want to capture the Event date fall within start date and End Date and one more point If Start date and End date can be + or - five days near.

Comment: " Start date and End date can be + or - five days near" can you explain this and alos post the text data not an image

Comment: komatiraju032 added data and hope its clear

Comment: add the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this should be what you want

```
df["between"] = df["EVENT DATE"].between(df["Start Date"],df["END DATE"])
df["+5d"] = (df["EVENT DATE"]-pd.to_timedelta("5d")).between(df["Start Date"],df["END DATE"])
df["-5d"] = (df["EVENT DATE"]+pd.to_timedelta("5d")).between(df["Start Date"],df["END DATE"])
print(df)

      V EVENT DATE Start Date   END DATE  between    +5d    -5d
0   AA1 2019-08-08 2019-08-05 2019-08-15     True  False   True
1   AA2 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 2019-08-15     True  False   True
2   AA3 2019-08-08 2019-08-08 2019-08-08     True  False  False
3   AA4 2019-08-08 2019-08-06 2019-08-15     True  False   True
4   AA5 2019-08-08 2019-08-15 2019-08-20    False  False  False
5   AA6 2019-08-08 2019-08-12 2019-08-20    False  False   True
```